# Emulator in Android for HTC Desire

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me how do i establish HTC Desire Emulator in my Eclipse.

I have already tried, available packages installation, but HTC is not there in third party packages.

Answer (score 9):

There isn't a specific HTC emulator - rather you use the generic Android emulator and change the characteristics of it to match whatever model of phone and version of Andriod you want to target.

You need to install the Android SDK and use it to create Virtual Devices (AVDs).  These can then be used to test your code before moving onto a physical device.

For detailed instructions see http://www.android.com.

Answer (score 4):

Please check this question. You can achieve htc-desire like emulator by setting appropriate values.. 
[The correct Eclipse/Android device configuration for HTC Desire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703124/the-correct-eclipse-android-device-configuration-for-htc-desire)