# The correct Eclipse/Android device configuration for HTC Desire

Tags: android-emulator, android

I want to create an Android Virtual Device in Eclipse Galileo which matches HTC Desire. What configuration options should I use?

Using ADT r10.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Octavian's answer was a good start (thanks), but I needed some more and couldn't wait. So after some semi-thourough research:

*(All this is for Eclipse Galileo with Android ADT plugin r10)*

**Target:** Android 2.1 or 2.2
*HTC Desire is shipped with 2.1 but upgradeable to 2.2. Version 2.3 expected to be available May or June 2011.*

**SD Card:** Shipped with 4GB (4096 MiB), supports 32GB (32768 MiB) .

**Snapshot:** New since ADT r9. Unrelated to the actual device, leave unchecked if uncertain.

**Skin:** WVGA800

**Hardware:**
Abstracted LCD Density -> 240
Max VM application heap size -> 24
Device RAM size -> 576

*Property "Device RAM size" needs to be added with [New...] for Android 2.1 and 2.2.*
*24MB application heap size seems to be standard on 2.1 and 2.2, however it can be tweaked, so watch out when emulating rooted stuff (in which case more of these settings might be for the birds anyway).*

*References:*
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Desire
http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_desire-3077.php
http://tools.android.com/recent/emulatorsnapshots
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=740752&highlight=vm+heap

Answer (score 12):

The closest you may get is using the following settings.

- Skin: 480x800 WVGA800
- Abstracted LCD density: 240
- Device ram size: 576 MB

Comment: +1 For this.  Also, if you start the emulator manually (instead of automatically when clicking run) you can even set the scaling to match the physical dimension of 3.7 inches.

Comment: Do you also know the setting for "Max VM Application Heap size"?

Answer (score 0):

For the display configuration you should set the resolution of the virtual device to 480×800 (WVGA)