# app not running on HTC desire

Tags: android

I made an android app that runs nicely on Samsung Galaxy S1, Galaxy S2 and the emulator. I sent the apk of it to someone who has an HTC desire device, and when he tried to install the app he said he got an error:

```
There was an error parsing the package.
```

As I don't own an HTC myself, i tried to setup an emulator with the specs as close as I can to the ones of HTC desire device, which i got from here: [The correct Eclipse/Android device configuration for HTC Desire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703124/the-correct-eclipse-android-device-configuration-for-htc-desire) 
The app runs nicely on my emulator with those settings, but isn't installing on the actual device. Any ideas what can be causing this? How do I find the problem?


this is the beginning of the Manifest if relevent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="memo.ori.friend"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
android:debuggable="true">
```

HTC desire android version is 2.2, Which is what I chose when I created this project. All phones checked on are checked to allow installations of apps from unknown sources. there are about 5 drawables in this app, which i have put in res/drawable-hdpi . i thought maybe the HTC is looking for them on res/drawable-mdpi so I have copied them there as well, but got the same result.

Appriciate any help, I'll supply you with any other information you think is relevent, I'm not exactly sure where to look :/

Comment: what is android version of ur application?what is android version of ur galaxy s1,s2 and what is android version of htc desire?

Comment: Is your APK signed? If not check this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) which should help while installing and running it on a real device.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to install the app in a device with Android version lower than 8, you have written that the min sdk version capable of running the app is 8. But the error message that you posted , not seems to go in that way... Did you built the package correctly? Did you picked the correct .apk?

Comment: I think so. This is the same apk from the workspace/app_name/bin/ and it worked on both S1 and S2. If the android version of the HTC is 2.2, isn't it insuring it's capable of running level 8?

Comment: @AamirKhan app version is 2.2. same goes for the desire.

Comment: @TimVK why do i need to sign the app? it worked with the debugging signature on other devices. all devices I ran the app on are configured for allowing 'run apps from unknown sources' option in Main -> Settings -> Applications -> Check Allow.. This is true for the HTC desire, S1 and S2.

Comment: Are those devices connected to the development PC or not and are the devices set with USB Debugging enabled then? I know that when I developed my app and I wanted to run it on my X10 without setting my X10 as debugging device I needed to sign my APK. That's also the reason why I proposed it. Hopefully you'll find/get to the answer fast.

Comment: If the Android version of your device is 2.2 (Froyo), yes, this version has api level 8, so must be capable of running app with api level 8 and lower. So this is not the reason of your issue. Also your apk seems that come from the correct place, from the /bin/ folder. Mmm, do you have the option of install in your device apps from external developers checked?

Comment: thanks. what would you suggest checking?

Comment: thanks, i appriciate it. devices are not connected to the dev PC, and i didn't enable USB debugging. the app just ran on both Samsung S1 and S2. So i don't know.

Comment: Try to check if your device has the option to allow install apps from unknown sources, and check it. Maybe in Settings > Applications

Comment: yes this is checked and allowed..

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure the problem is that the Android Version on the HTC Desire is below API Level 8. The Desire was originally shipped with Android 2.1 which is API Level 7 as far as i know.

I discoverd the same error a few days ago while trying to install one of my apps on an Samsung Galaxy S1. My App was designed for API Level 10, and i found out that the Samsung Galaxy S1 has never been updated and running on Andoid 2.2.

I guess your Problem is similar, the Android Version on the Desire is to low.

UPDATE:

As litte resarch lead to this:
As i wrote above the error can be caused by to low API-Level (according to installed Android Version, you find a Table with Android Version - API Level here) on the phone.
But the error can also be caused by:
Renaming the *.apk file after it was created automatically, and on some Devices this seems to happen when you install it from SD Card.
Also some trouble - somethings resulting in this error - is reported when trying to install directly from an Mail-Attchment.

So if this error happens to you, make sure to:
1. Make sure the Android Version on the phone is high enough
2. Do not rename the apk-File after it was created
3. Do not try to install directly from an Mail-Attachment
4. Do not install from SD-Card, try it from intern phone Memory

If this all dont help, then it would actually be time to look in the Manifest since its a parsing error, but this cant be the solution in your case since its running on some other devices.

Comment: thanks! is there a way to tell whats the api level on the htc? i don't see this information on Settings -> About, just the Android version which is 2.2. I want to be positive this is the case. If it is, what can we do?

Comment: I will ask if he tried to install from SD-Card. I sent him the .apk file by email so i'm not sure. and what do you mean by renaming the apk? i don't think it is renamed since it was created in /bin

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! I will look it up and tell you if this was the case shortly. thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1555863 
I updated the answer, please accept if it helped you.

Comment: thanks again for your help. indeed you are helpful and i appreciate that, but: 1) the app runs on all other devices 2) i have checked for everything you said (SD-Card, Mail attachments, renaming of .apk) and apparently this isn't the case here. Sadly, the app still doesn't run on the HTC desire with all that said. Accepting your answer, helpful as may be, meaning that the issue is solved and also indicating others that i've got a solution, which i don't. I wouldn't want them to assume it's solved and not encourage someone who might know of whats the problem to help. sorry

Comment: @user1555863 dont panic, i wrote "...if it helped you"

Comment: just keeping you posted :) i'm beginning to feel a little skeptic about getting a solution here :/

Comment: yes, could happen that you wont get a solution for that problem. The last thing that came to my mind, is you should find somebody else with a HTC Desire and try to install on this Device, so you know for sure that it dont work on a Desire and that there are not some strange things going on with this specific Desire you tried it on...

Answer (score 0):

Where is your Activity Running in your manifest ?
Manifest should have a Start Activity to launch it  Like

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="7"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: Of course this is included in the rest of my app's Manifest. **App wouldn't be running on emulator and s1 and s2 without this i assume**